# wrap() function dependent on parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-wrap

I have two links with two different megamenu settings:

- The `toggle` uses a `click` effect along with a `3 column width` dropdown (`column-width-3`, `mode-click`).
- The `Products` link uses a `hover` effect along with a `full width column` (`column-justify`, `mode-hover`).

Source code:

```js
if ($("uk-navbar-container").has(".mega-menu-active")) {

  var get_id = $(".uk-navbar-dropdown-grid").prop('id');
  // console.log( get_id );


  if ($('#' + get_id).hasClass("column-justify")) {
    if ($('#' + get_id).hasClass("mode-click")) {
      $('.uk-navbar-dropdown-grid').wrap('<div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" uk-drop="mode:click;"></div>');
    } else {
      $('.uk-navbar-dropdown-grid').wrap('<div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" uk-drop="..."></div>');
    }
  } else {

    if ($('#' + get_id).hasClass("mode-click")) {
      $('.uk-navbar-dropdown-grid').wrap('<div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" uk-drop="mode:click;"></div>');
    } else {
      $('.uk-navbar-dropdown-grid').wrap('<div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" uk-drop="..."></div>');
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-navbar-left">
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">

    <a href="#" class="uk-navbar-toggle mega-menu-active"><span class="toggle-icon"></span></a>

    <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown uk-navbar-dropdown-width-3" uk-drop="...">
      <div id="megamenu-954" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid uk-grid column-width-3 mode-click megamenu-954">
        <div class="uk-width-1-3">
          <ul class="uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <li id="menu-item-950" class="mega-menu-active">
      <a href="#">Products</a>

      <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" uk-drop="...">
        <div id="megamenu-946" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid column-justify mode-hover megamenu-946">

          <div class="uk-width-1-3">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
              <li>...</li>
              <li>...</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

I use the `wrap()` function to add a bit of extra code to make the `click/hover` and `column width` possible.

The problem that I have is that, although the `Products` link has `column-justify` and `mode-hover` classes, the width is `column-width-3` (same as `toggle`).

Plus for both, the hover effect is used for both links (while `toggle` alone should be on `click mode` and `hover mode` is for the `Products` link).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: '#'.get_id <- theres no get_id in the String.prototype

Comment: I think you want string concatenation, but `'#'.get_id` doesn't do it, in `js` it's `'#' + get_id`.

Comment: Changed it to `'#' + get_id` but my problem still remains the same. When I use `console.log( get_id );` it only lists `megamenu-954` (the first id link), shouldn't it also grab the second link id?

Comment: @kiarashi It shouldn't. Use loop/each/map to get ids of all elements in a set.

Comment: Could you create an example? I'm still a newbie when it comes to jquery/js.